# How do I get my anchor tag to open a page in a new tab?

Tags: javascript, html, angular

```
<a [href]="urlByEnvironment()">{{ 'main.journey.return-link' | translate }}</a>

urlByEnvironment = () => {window.open(this.environment.options.urls, '_blank');}
```

I am struggling with getting my link to open correctly. As the code currently is, the html anchor calls the method in the component (urlByEnvironment) which returns a url depending on which environment I am in.

What actually happens is, the link, called by the function, opens in a new tab without the user clicking on the hyperlink text. When the hyperlink is clicked, it just reloads the page. The correct link is opened in a new tab initially, but not when the hyperlink is clicked.

I have tried to use (click) instead of [href] this works almost as desired but the link doesnt appear in the correct style and the hand pointer doesn't change when hoevering.

The other method I have tried it to put the window.open() directly into the anchor tag using string interpolation but this doesn't work either.

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: `but the link doesnt appear in the correct style` Could you elaborate on that or give a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)?

Answer (score 2):

This happens because your `urlByEnvironment()` method actually opens a new tab when called. And it will be run each time change detection occurs, so it might actually try opening multiple new tabs (although browser would probably block that behavior by itself).

You should simply bind the value to the `href` and keep the `target` in the template, e.g.

```
<a [href]="urlByEnvironment()" target="_blank">{{ 'main.journey.return-link' | translate }}</a>
```

Then your `urlByEnvironment()` should return only the actual url:

```
urlByEnvironment = () => this.environment.options.urls;
```

On a side note, you should avoid binding template properties to functions since it can cause unnecessary change detection runs. You should try to bind them to the properties defined in the class.

In your case, you could just have something like:

```
linkUrl: string;

constructor() {
  this.linkUrl = this.environment.options.urls;
}
```

And then in your template:

```
<a [href]="linkUrl" target="_blank">{{ 'main.journey.return-link' | translate }}</a>
```

Comment: This worked perfectly. Also thank you for the advice on using the url directly instead of calling the function, it's definitely the more logical approach! I couldn't get it to work but I will try again. Thank you for the help!